# Can't understand a pointer to a fixed size array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am a newb to C++, and can't figure out how a pointer to a fixed size array works.

The book I am reading said:

```
short tell[10];
short (*pas)[20] = &tell;  //pas points to array of 20 shorts

...Thus, the type of pas is short(*)[20]. Also note that because pas is set to
&tell, *pas is equivalent to tell, so (*pas) [0] would be the first element of the array.
```

What I don't get is, **"If pas, is set to &tell, *pas is equivalent to tell. So, (*pas) [0] would be the first element of the array."**

I don't understand how if pas is set to &tell, which is the address of a 20-byte block of memory, and the ***pas** is equivalent to **tell**. Which means (*pas) [0] would be the first element of the array.

This is the first time that I saw this kind of pointers, so I really don't get how it works.

I apologize if this is a stupid question.

Thank you.

Comment: If you have a pointer to something, `*p` gets that something. That's true for any type of pointer. If you have an array, `arr[0]` gets the first element. Combine them.

Comment: Who wrote the book? That initialization can't possibly compile.

Comment: @T.C. C++ Primer Plus, sixth edition by Stephen Prata.

Comment: It's assuming I initialized the array.

Comment: @T.C.: It can compile, and it does under gcc with default settings. The assignment is a constraint violation, requiring a diagnostic. Under gcc (unfortunately IMHO), the diagnostic is merely a warning.

Comment: @KeithThompson It doesn't compile for any version of g++ I tested (4.6-4.9). It compiles with a warning if you use the C compiler, but the question is tagged C++.

Comment: @T.C.: Ah, I missed the tag. Never mind.

Comment: @Singularity: The example you posted is erroneous, and therefore can only mislead. It is not possible to legally do this `short (*pas)[20] = &tell` when `tell` has only 10 elements. The book you are reading obviously contains an error (a typo?)

Comment: @AndreyT I thought so, thanks for pointing it out. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array is a type of object in C++, so you can have a pointer-to-array, or a reference-to-array. The name of an array will *decay* to a pointer to its first element in many contexts, but it is *not* just a pointer to its first element. For example, given `int a[10]; int* i;`, then `sizeof(a)` is `sizeof(int) * 10` and is almost certainly *not* equal to `sizeof(i)`.

The syntax to declare a pointer to array is the ugly one shown in your book:

```
 short (*pas)[20]; // declare pas as a pointer to an array of 20 shorts
                   // pas is a single pointer
```

This is *completely* different from

```
 short *foo[20];   // declare foo as an array of 20 pointers to short
                   // foo is an array containing 20 pointers
```

You can take the address of an array and assign it to a pointer to array, just like you can take the address of an `int` variable and store it in a pointer to `int`:

```
 short stuff[20];
 pas = &stuff;      // pas now points to the array stuff
```

You can write a function that takes an array by reference:

```
 void f(short (&arr)[20]) { } // f takes an array of 20 shorts by reference

 short p[20];
 short *i = p;   // p decays to a pointer to its first element in this context,
                 // and the resulting pointer is used to initialize i
 f(p);           // ok, pass the array by reference
 f(i);           // compile error
```

Now, the code in the example is

```
short tell[10];
short (*pas)[20] = &tell;  //pas points to array of 20 shorts
```

which cannot compile because the type of `&tell` is "pointer to array of 10 `short`s", which can't be assigned to a variable of type "pointer to array of 20 `short`s".

Suppose we fix this code:

```
short tell[20];
short (*pas)[20] = &tell;  // now compiles! yay!
```

Then `pas` is a pointer to an array of 20 `short`s, and it points to the array `tell`. Dereferencing a "pointer to `T`" gives you the `T` the pointer points to, so dereferencing `pas` with `*pas` gives you the array of 20 `short`s `pas` points to. You can then use the subscript operator on this array, like any other arrays, bearing in mind that `[]` has higher precedence than `*` so you need to use parentheses:

```
short c = (*pas)[0];   // initializes c with the first element of the array pas points to
                       // since pas points to tell, this initializes c with tell[0].
```